# Java crashing badly

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have had some problems with java and MC, it happens (Before LWJGL loads) if Qcraft is on. :

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_IN_PAGE_ERROR (0xc0000006) at pc=0x7c342eee, pid=5292, tid=1636
#
# JRE version: 6.0_14-b08
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.0-b16 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [msvcr71.dll+0x2eee]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x01a9a400):  JavaThread "Minecraft main thread" [_thread_in_native, id=1636, stack(0x00160000,0x001b0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000006, ExceptionInformation=0x00000001 0x283db000 0xc0000185 

Registers:
EAX=0x2e95767e, EBX=0x00000200, ECX=0x00000076, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x001aee28, EBP=0x001aee30, ESI=0x2e9574a6, EDI=0x283db000
EIP=0x7c342eee, EFLAGS=0x00010216

Top of Stack: (sp=0x001aee28)
0x001aee28:   291d9850 291db9e0 001aee54 6d7f6366
0x001aee38:   283dafd8 2e95747e 00000200 291db9e0
0x001aee48:   291d9850 2980d6e8 283dafd8 001aeea0
0x001aee58:   6d7f50bb 291d9850 2e95747e 00000000
0x001aee68:   0000000d 291db9e0 fffffffb 7c3416b3
0x001aee78:   01a90000 00000000 7c3416b8 291db9e0
0x001aee88:   01a9a510 00000000 00007950 00000004
0x001aee98:   2e9576c0 00000000 001aeec0 6d7f4c76 

Instructions: (pc=0x7c342eee)
0x7c342ede:   00 00 00 75 14 c1 e9 02 83 e2 03 83 f9 08 72 28
0x7c342eee:   f3 a5 ff 24 95 0c 30 34 7c 8b c7 ba 03 00 00 00 


Stack: [0x00160000,0x001b0000],  sp=0x001aee28,  free space=315k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [msvcr71.dll+0x2eee]
C  [zip.dll+0x6366]
C  [zip.dll+0x50bb]
C  [zip.dll+0x4c76]
C  [zip.dll+0x1807]
J  java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes([BII)I
J  java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate([BII)I
J  java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read([BII)I
J  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCache.loadFromStream(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)J
J  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageInputStream.read([BII)I
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.SubImageInputStream.read([BII)I+25
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.InputStreamAdapter.read([BII)I+7
j  java.io.SequenceInputStream.read([BII)I+58
J  java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill()V
J  java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read([BII)I
j  java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill()V+175
J  java.io.BufferedInputStream.read()I
J  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(IIIIIII)V
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage()V+50
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Ljavax/imageio/ImageReadParam;)V+325
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(ILjavax/imageio/ImageReadParam;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+17
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Ljavax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+55
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+20
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.func_130100_a(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/Resource;)V+24
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.load(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/ResourceManager;Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;)Z+8
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110571_b(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/ResourceManager;)V+158
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110551_a(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/ResourceManager;)V+6
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110579_a(Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/texture/TextureObject;)Z+7
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110580_a(Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/texture/TickableTextureObject;)Z+3
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_130088_a(Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/texture/TextureMap;)Z+3
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a()V+909
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d()V+6
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+768
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xecabc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x173d61]
V  [jvm.dll+0xecb3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18dfeb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18e7f6]
V  [jvm.dll+0x1176c3]
C  [java.dll+0x714f]
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch([Ljava/lang/String;)V+657
j  net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xecabc]
V  [jvm.dll+0x173d61]
V  [jvm.dll+0xecb3d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf5705]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfd35d]
C  [javaw.exe+0x2155]
C  [javaw.exe+0x833e]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x4ed6c]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637eb]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x637be]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J  java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes([BII)I
J  java.util.zip.Inflater.inflate([BII)I
J  java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read([BII)I
J  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCache.loadFromStream(Ljava/io/InputStream;J)J
J  javax.imageio.stream.MemoryCacheImageInputStream.read([BII)I
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.SubImageInputStream.read([BII)I+25
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.common.InputStreamAdapter.read([BII)I+7
j  java.io.SequenceInputStream.read([BII)I+58
J  java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill()V
J  java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read([BII)I
j  java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill()V+175
J  java.io.BufferedInputStream.read()I
J  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(IIIIIII)V
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage()V+50
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Ljavax/imageio/ImageReadParam;)V+325
j  com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(ILjavax/imageio/ImageReadParam;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+17
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Ljavax/imageio/stream/ImageInputStream;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+55
j  javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;)Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;+20
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.func_130100_a(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/Resource;)V+24
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.load(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/ResourceManager;Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;)Z+8
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110571_b(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/ResourceManager;)V+158
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110551_a(Lnet/minecraft/client/resources/ResourceManager;)V+6
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110579_a(Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/texture/TextureObject;)Z+7
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110580_a(Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/texture/TickableTextureObject;)Z+3
j  net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_130088_a(Lnet/minecraft/util/ResourceLocation;Lnet/minecraft/client/renderer/texture/TextureMap;)Z+3
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a()V+909
j  net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d()V+6
j  net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+768
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch([Ljava/lang/String;)V+657
j  net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+8
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x01a0fc00 JavaThread "Timer hack thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4000, stack(0x29bf0000,0x29c40000)]
  0x282d0800 JavaThread "Snooper Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1328, stack(0x29b20000,0x29b70000)]
  0x0195dc00 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3224, stack(0x290b0000,0x29100000)]
  0x2821a400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5200, stack(0x284f0000,0x28540000)]
  0x280b5800 JavaThread "Thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5836, stack(0x284a0000,0x284f0000)]
  0x01a0cc00 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4968, stack(0x27e00000,0x27e50000)]
  0x019f9c00 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4828, stack(0x27db0000,0x27e00000)]
  0x019f5400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5028, stack(0x27d60000,0x27db0000)]
  0x019ea800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4172, stack(0x27d10000,0x27d60000)]
  0x019bf000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5880, stack(0x27cc0000,0x27d10000)]
  0x019ba800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2312, stack(0x01a30000,0x01a80000)]
=>0x01a9a400 JavaThread "Minecraft main thread" [_thread_in_native, id=1636, stack(0x00160000,0x001b0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x019b6000 VMThread [stack: 0x012c0000,0x01310000] [id=5140]
  0x01a1f400 WatcherThread [stack: 0x27e50000,0x27ea0000] [id=4652]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 16256K, used 5659K [0x03aa0000, 0x04c40000, 0x06200000)
  eden space 14464K,  31% used [0x03aa0000, 0x03f05a68, 0x048c0000)
  from space 1792K,  64% used [0x048c0000, 0x049e14b8, 0x04a80000)
  to   space 1792K,   0% used [0x04a80000, 0x04a80000, 0x04c40000)
 tenured generation   total 215980K, used 170327K [0x06200000, 0x134eb000, 0x23aa0000)
   the space 215980K,  78% used [0x06200000, 0x10855ef0, 0x10856000, 0x134eb000)
 compacting perm gen  total 29952K, used 29893K [0x23aa0000, 0x257e0000, 0x27aa0000)
   the space 29952K,  99% used [0x23aa0000, 0x257d14c0, 0x257d1600, 0x257e0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x77c00000 - 0x77d3c000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77690000 - 0x77764000     C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75cc0000 - 0x75d0b000     C:\windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x774f0000 - 0x77590000     C:\windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x770e0000 - 0x7718c000     C:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x77d70000 - 0x77d89000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x775e0000 - 0x77682000     C:\windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77190000 - 0x77259000     C:\windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x77590000 - 0x775de000     C:\windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77e20000 - 0x77e2a000     C:\windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x77930000 - 0x779cd000     C:\windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x761f0000 - 0x7620f000     C:\windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x77420000 - 0x774ec000     C:\windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6da8b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x73b10000 - 0x73b42000     C:\windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x75b40000 - 0x75b8c000     C:\windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x77d60000 - 0x77d65000     C:\windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x76210000 - 0x76245000     C:\windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x77d50000 - 0x77d56000     C:\windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x75680000 - 0x756bc000     C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x75670000 - 0x75676000     C:\windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x74f20000 - 0x74f71000     C:\windows\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x76f20000 - 0x7707c000     C:\windows\system32\ole32.dll
0x74760000 - 0x748fe000     C:\windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\comctl32.dll
0x77080000 - 0x770d7000     C:\windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74320000 - 0x74333000     C:\windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x744c0000 - 0x74500000     C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x75b90000 - 0x75b9c000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76250000 - 0x76e9a000     C:\windows\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d230000 - 0x6d284000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7af000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\unpack.dll
0x29060000 - 0x290ac000     C:\Users\Coey\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\versions\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965\1.6.4-Forge9.11.1.965-natives-54965481611709\lwjgl.dll
0x29900000 - 0x299c8000     C:\windows\system32\OPENGL32.dll
0x6ff20000 - 0x6ff42000     C:\windows\system32\GLU32.dll
0x6cef0000 - 0x6cfd7000     C:\windows\system32\DDRAW.dll
0x720e0000 - 0x720e6000     C:\windows\system32\DCIMAN32.dll
0x779d0000 - 0x77b6d000     C:\windows\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x75e90000 - 0x75eb7000     C:\windows\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x778a0000 - 0x7792f000     C:\windows\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x75f80000 - 0x75f92000     C:\windows\system32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x74f80000 - 0x74f89000     C:\windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x756c0000 - 0x756d6000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x75460000 - 0x7549b000     C:\windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x752b0000 - 0x752c7000     C:\windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x75c40000 - 0x75c4b000     C:\windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x74f10000 - 0x74f20000     C:\windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x74f00000 - 0x74f10000     C:\windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x74ee0000 - 0x74ef2000     C:\windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x74eb0000 - 0x74ed4000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x74e80000 - 0x74ea1000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x750b0000 - 0x750cc000     C:\windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x750a0000 - 0x750a7000     C:\windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x75540000 - 0x75584000     C:\windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x74e70000 - 0x74e78000     C:\windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x74de0000 - 0x74de5000     C:\windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74df0000 - 0x74df6000     C:\windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74e00000 - 0x74e38000     C:\windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x2a0f0000 - 0x2a4e2000     C:\windows\system32\ig4icd32.dll
0x2a4f0000 - 0x2a78a000     C:\windows\system32\ig4dev32.dll
0x73fc0000 - 0x74039000     C:\windows\system32\mscms.dll
0x6ceb0000 - 0x6cee8000     C:\windows\system32\icm32.dll
0x6d560000 - 0x6d569000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
0x6d790000 - 0x6d798000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x75d10000 - 0x75e30000     C:\windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x75cb0000 - 0x75cbc000     C:\windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
```

I think there was one working question, but it didn't make sense.

Comment: It seems to be having problems with some PNGs - does it happen with the vanilla version (or a freshly downloaded one)? EDIT: You say this occurs with qCraft enabled. So without it, everything works fine?

Comment: No, I got another crash using Dimensional Doors going through a dimension.

Comment: Just to check - you are using the right versions of everything, right? For example, qCraft requires MC 1.5.2.

Comment: I think your Java version is not up to date. Try updating it before doing anything else

Comment: Yep. qCraft is right, I got it from tekkit main (not illegal because I am not reselling it, don't worry) and I don't remember where I got Dimensional Doors

Comment: qCraft appears to be a mod. Therefore, this question is off-topic as a modded minecraft crash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because tech support for modded Minecraft is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

> ExceptionCode=0xc0000006

AFAIK, Windows uses this code for memory paging problems.  More specifically, it tried mapping part of a file into memory, and this failed for some reason.  This is a media error: if you're loading Minecraft from a network disk, the network may be experiencing issues; if you're loading it from a local disk, your disk is having trouble reading its data.

At any rate, using a different Java version is unlikely to help.

> ExceptionInformation=0x00000001 0x283db000 **0xc0000185**

`0xc0000185` is an I/O error reported by the storage unit itself ("The I/O device reported an I/O error").  If this happens regularly, it may be caused by **bad sectors**, which is usually an indication that the disk is about to fail permanently soon.

Check the SMART status on your disk<sup>(1)</sup>.  I don't think Windows has a built-in utility for that, so you may have to download one, or you can create a bootable Linux installation on a pen drive and use its disk utility.  (You may want that Linux installation for [rescuing the data](http://www.garloff.de/kurt/linux/ddrescue/) on your disk anyway.)

<sub>(1) I've heard that some Seagate drives (drive ID starts with 'ST') don't correctly report SMART status such as failed writes and bad sectors.  I haven't personally experienced any of that, but it's worth keeping in mind.</sub>

Comment: Finally, someone who is good a deciphering crash reports. Nice answer!